# Why does WebRTC/TURNS not work for every client?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, rfc5766turnserver

We previously configured our clients to use a TURN server at `turn:ourTurn.com:443`. A customer with very strict network rules could not use our WebRTC services, but when updating the ICE server to `turns:ourTurnserver.com:443?transport=tcp` (note the added `S` in `turns` vs `turn` and TCP as transport protocol) it resolved their issue.

Unfortunately, this made our service unavailable to many other customers (no idea why, we expected the 'strictest' config with TURNS/TLS to work all the time). So we implemented the 'gold standard' implementation where the clients use a list of ICE servers, i.e.
`[stun:ourTurnserver.com:443, turn:ourTurnserver.com:443?transport=udp, turn:ourTurnserver.com:443?transport=tcp, turns:ourTurnserver.com:443?transport=tcp]`

Now our service works again for all users, EXCEPT those behind the very strict firewall.

Note that the new configuration (list of ICE servers) **includes** the TURNS address, which made the config work for the strict firewall in the first place.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: By enabling secure TURN over TLS on port 443, you've made the traffic indistinguishable from encrypted HTTPS. No idea why that wouldn't work universally. Have you considered doing an ICE Gathering check up front with each individual TURN config until success? Then when you do your actual "call", use that config from the pre-test.

Comment: Also, when you say, "made our service unavailable to many other"... do you mean that those customers can't even get srflx and relay addresses?  Or do you get the full set of addresses in both exchanged SDPs, but fail to connect after that?

Comment: do you have details on the "very strict firewall"? If it includes proxies that do deep packet inspection there is no way around that but talking to the network admin.

Comment: After "enforcing" TURNS (only providing TURNS), some customers did not even receive ICE candidates. 
Unfortunately, we do not have details on the firewall configurations. But I assumed that TURNS/TLS should be fine in any case, since the config must allow 443 to enable any encrypted traffic like HTTPS?